# c++: XOR'd string with special characters won't compile as raw string literal?

Tags: c++, string, unicode, xor, literals

I have a string I've obfuscated in my code, by XORing each character by some random value.

However, the resulting multi-line raw string literal won't compile correctly.

In the following image, you can see how MSVS2015 is not parsing the string correctly, even when using proper delimeters on either end (notice the black text throughout, not being parsed as part of the string).

Trying to compile the code results in errors about not being able to find the closing brace of the literal (even though it's in the proper place, at the very end of the string after the closing delimeter, etc). Manually erasing the black bits results in a proper compilation (albeit with a string that can no longer be properly unscrambled, of course).

[image]

I'm assuming this is happening because various resulting characters of the XOR function cannot be properly saved inside the .h file. Is there a solution to this problem? I've tried switching the file format to Unicode but that didn't work.

Comment: Please don't show print screen of code.

Comment: Perhaps you should consider some other way of encoding your string? Perhaps some kind of hex-encoding scheme or a something which result in plain ASCII characters? And of course make sure the string literal isn't [to long](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sx08afx2.aspx).

Comment: @user23573 he is using raw strings. escaping characters is not an issue

Comment: @bolov How else am I suppose to show how MSVS is parsing the string? Just copying it as code into the stackoverflow comment form will not bring over the formatting.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude While that's a potential workaround, that doesn't help me understand why this is happening in the first place. A MSVS bug, perhaps?

Comment: @Tyson hmm... ok this could be a case where print screen is acceptable. I am with some programmer dude on this one: use a scheme where in the end you have ASCII characters. The issue with what you have now is that not all byte values are valid utf8 bytes.

Comment: @user23573 I don't understand what you mean

Comment: How *long* is the string? Is it longer than 2048 characters?

Comment: Source code may only contain characters from the *source character set*, which is implementation-defined. That means the compiler documentation must have somewhere that specifies what characters you can use.

Comment: @M.M: That's Unicode, in the case of MSVC++.

Comment: Not my votes, but this probably isn't a minimal example. (And the question should have mentioned if it was minimal)

Comment: @MSalters Does it include characters sub-32? The image in OP's post suggests control characters are possible.

Comment: @MSalters also it's implementation-defined how the actual characters in the file are mapped onto the source character set (e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16 with BOM etc. etc.)  ; perhaps OP has managed to create a file that doesn't comply with that requirement

Comment: Gentlemen, why all these downvotes? This question is not as stupid as it sounds. And most of you commentators are wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Your use of raw strings is too simplistic. It takes the sequence `..|..` as delimiter, you probably don't have the sequence `)..|..` at the end of your string.

Use the full specification of delimited raw strings as described [in cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) in variant (6). This is also described in the C++ standard section §2.14.5 String literals. The template is as follows:

> R"*d-char-sequence*(*your raw text*)*d-char-sequence*"

The key is to use the *"d-char-sequence"*. This sequence can contain the following:

> any member of the basic source character set except:
>   space, the left parenthesis (, the right parenthesis ), the backslash \,
>   and the control characters representing horizontal tab,
>   vertical tab, form feed, and newline.

How that *d-char-sequence* works is described as follows:

> A string literal that has an R in the prefix is a raw string literal. The d-char-sequence serves as a delimiter. The terminating d-char-sequence of a raw-string is the same sequence of characters as the initial d-char-sequence. A d-char-sequence shall consist of at most 16 characters.

This ensures that the raw string can legally contain any character that is supported by the source character set (unicode here). The raw string may contain quotes parentheses backslashes and even newlines.

It's not as complicated as it sounds. Just add a prefix and a suffix to the raw string. It could look like this:

```
std::string(R"my-delimiter(... long text ...)my-delimiter");
```

Of course substitute `... long text ...` with the raw string literal. Just make sure that the sequence `)my-delimiter"` does not appear in the raw string text.

Comment: This doesn't explain why "Manually erasing the black bits results in a proper compilation ", per the question. If the delimiter is missing at the end, removal of a string in the middle won't fix it.

Comment: I have a proper delimiter at the end, as stated in the original question.